# Distinct is not working as expected

Tags: mysql, distinct

I am using `distinct` in my `query`, but it still gives me duplicate enteries in `id`. What am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
SELECT distinct(sd_did),sd_uid,sd_time 
FROM shared_deals 
WHERE sd_uid = '".$uid."' 
ORDER BY sd_time DESC";
```

Comment: Could you give an example of possible duplicate data in your table, and what you expect your query to return? I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve...

Answer (score 5):

Distinct here probably works only on one field, if you have other values also being fetched you can try

```
SELECT sd_did,sd_uid,sd_time 
FROM shared_deals 
WHERE sd_uid = '".$uid."' 
GROUP BY sd_did
ORDER BY sd_time DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `distinct` works on all the selected columns, meaning if in your results you have `sd_did=1,sd_uid=1` and `sd_did=1,sd_uid=2` the distinct will not work as you expect, because the two rows are different

Comment: ops.than is there have any other solution through which i get the distinct sd_did all ?

Comment: If you only need `sd_did`, just do `SELECT sd_did FROM ...`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the combination of (sd_did,sd_uid,sd_time) to be distinct, use the code below :

```
SELECT       sd_did
             ,sd_uid
             ,sd_time 
FROM         shared_deals 
WHERE        sd_uid = '".$uid."' 
GROUP BY     sd_did,sd_uid,sd_time
ORDER BY     sd_time DESC;
```